# How to prevent disappearing of Iframe content

Tags: asp.net, iframe, powerpoint

I have input parameters in my page with four frames . I used Export to Excel , PPT and Print functions in my page. 
The problem is when i use Export to PPT function , the page and iframe waits till the PPT takes the values and reloads and the contents of iframe disappears once the PPT is opened.

I used  Microsoft.Office.Interop for doing this PPT function. I didnt find any problems with Iframe contet when I use Excel and Print functions. I need to stop diappearing the contents of iframe ?? The same happens in all browsers .Any suggestions .